# get a string line from bunch of text that contain specific word(s) with php

Tags: php, string

I have some code generated by FCKEditor, eg. as follow :

```
$content = "<p>some text with some tags and so on.. [here is html tag image source with image url] another some text with some tags and so on.. </p>";
```

I assigned all those code into a variable called `$content`.

I want to "extract" and grep only the image source url from `$content` and put the result into variable `$img_url`, so I can echo the `$img_url`

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: I tried to fix the markdown formatting, please check if the HTML is correctly modified by me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one image tag you can directly use this

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
   $string = " ".$string;
     $ini = strpos($string,$start);
     if ($ini == 0) return "";
     $ini += strlen($start);    
     $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
     return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

echo $img_url = get_string_between($content,'<img src="','</img>');
```

If You have multiple then you should explode the $content and use the function as u wanted.

Comment: thanks for the respond @Arasu, but still return empty

below is the real code:
   <p style="text-align: center; "><img width="300" height="225" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; " border="2" align="left" alt="" src="/datafitur/news_img/1/201109/Steve-Jobs.jpg" /><b><span style="font-size:14.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:.....</p>

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = '<p style="text-align: center; "><img width="300" height="225" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; " border="2" align="left" alt="" src="/datafitur/news_img/1/201109/Steve-Jobs.jpg" /><b><span style="font-size:14.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:.....</p>'

$explodeContent = explode('src=', $content);
$explodeSrc  = strstr($explodeContent[1], '/>', true);
$explodeSrc = trim($explodeSrc,'"');
$explodeSrc = trim($explodeSrc,' ');
```

Edit:

I have changed to use strstr instead of explode in the second step.